# Pulling json decode array results

Tags: php, arrays, json

So, I accessed the results successfully like:

```
    $get = $this->getAllResults()->getContent();
    $pull = json_decode($get);
    $results = $pull->data->items[0];
```

Now, when I debug on dump() of

> ```
>    dump($results->myDataResultOne);die
> ```

or:

> ```
>    dump($results->myDataResultTwo);die;
> ```

it access my results, but I can't get that same result in foreach like:

```
$rows = [];

    $rows[] = array(
        "my first result",
        "my second result",
    );

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $rows[] = array(
            $row->myDataResultOne,
            $row->myDataResultTwo
        );
    }
```

Instead, it throws:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: what if you call `var_dump(gettype($row));` inside the loop? The error is really specific, you are not dealing with an object

Comment: It returns: string(7) "integer" @AndreaGolin

Comment: then $row is an integer and def not an object. Try to print what $results actually is, before the loop. You could do a simple `echo "<pre>"; print_r($results); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: on dumping results it prints: object(stdClass)#4640 (31) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["myDataResultOne"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["myDataResultTwo"]=>
  NULL @AndreaGolin

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
        $rows[] = array(
            $row->myDataResult
        );
    }
```

with

```
foreach ($results->myDataResult as $row) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: I think it won't work, because myDataResults represents just first column and I have three.. I updated answer for better understanding. Thanks. @Gulshan

Answer (score 0):

Based on the dump of $results you give on comments, you are actually trying to foreach an object, not an array of items.

You could simply access your object methods and properties directly like:

`$results->myDataResultOne`

and that is why you get it correctly when you tried to dump it.

When you try to to iterate an object you enter the realm of  [object iteration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php), and you end up iterating your obj structure with a key => value pattern. 
In your case, you could do:

```
foreach($results AS $key => $value){
  var_dump($key);  // for the first iteration, it should be "id" (string)
  var_dump($value); // for the first iteration, it should be 1 ()
}
```

Note that i wrote this code on memory and it could be wrong, but it should give you some hints.